# Understanding the Sequelize Pool.Idle Setting?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, amazon-rds

The [Sequelize docs for pool.idle](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/sequelize.js%7Esequelize#instance-constructor-constructor) say it is:

> The maximum time, in milliseconds, that a connection can be idle
> before being released.

But on a [github issues page](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9595), a Sequelize [contributor](https://sushantdhiman.com/projects) says:

> Basically, idle decides if a connection is idle or not, say if
> connection is not used for 15sec then it is idle.

This suggests that `pool.idle` has nothing to do with the connection being released, apparently contradicting the Sequelize documentation.

The same comment continues:

> Being "idle" does not mean it will get removed from pool. It is evict
> that will remove any idle connection. As per your config, evictor will
> run every 10sec and check if there are any idle connection to remove.

I.e. `pool.idle` just says how long a connection can be unused before it is marked as `idle`.

Which is correct? Or, are both somehow correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Documentation:** https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/aws-lambda/ 
All the Sequelize connections are pushed to **pool** after finishing the query execution. Idle and evict are part of the pool configuration.

**Idle(not working):** This is the wait time(milliseconds) for a DB connection to consider idle(free) before being used for other query/queries execution. After passing this time connections will be considered as idle and all idle connections will be pushed to **sequelize pool**.

**Evict:** The time interval, in milliseconds, after which **sequelize-pool** will remove idle connections.

**Example:** Let's say we've a **DB: products**. We established a DB connection: **seqConnection** using sequelize by providing
`pool: {idle: 160000,evict: 180000} // idle: 2min. evict: 3min`

1. If you don't use the seqConnection for 2 minutes it will be considered idle.
2. Now you can retain idle seqConnection from sequelize-pool within 3 minutes.
3. If you don't retain idle seqConnection within 3 minutes then it will be destroyed/removed from the sequelize-pool.
   **NOTE:** On this point, if you're playing just with a single DB connection at
   a time. i.e. `pool: {max:1}` and you want a connection then you've
   to create a new DB connection.